# Multiple Instances of an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to show the user information on incoming-call screen, whenever there is an incoming-call. So I have a broadcast receiver listening to incoming calls, which starts the intent service, which subsequently starts an activity (*with Theme Dialog*).

Now, whenever there is an incoming-call, my activity dialog pops up and shows as intended.

**Problem**:  When the activity dialog is already on the screen and incoming-call happens, there is no new activity dialog with new information. I guess that whenever there is an instance, Android does not creates the new one.  So it seems like my problem is "*creating multiple instances of an activity*".

Please note that I am starting an activity from an intent service using **FLAG_NEW_TASK**.

Comment: are you talking about an Activity or an Application, because on Android, an Application can only run once at the same time.

Comment: @Nickolaus : Activity with theme Dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Google Doc says :

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

> "When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity
>   you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started;
>   instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the
>   screen with the state it was last in."

So, if you want to start **a new fresh activity** then simply not use this flag only, you should use it with [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) for the desired result.

For Example:

```
// Sets the Activity to start in a new, empty task
notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

If the above solution is not what you needed, then have a look at
    [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) attribute, declare this attribute with the desired options (i.e. as per your need) in `activity` tag of `manifest` file.

Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: Not working, it just updates the Present activity on the Screen.

Comment: if still not working then you may want to call finish() before the startActivity(intent).

Answer (score 2):

Use flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK which according to the documentation :

```
Used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to disable the behavior of bringing an existing task to the foreground. When set, a new task is always started to host the Activity for the Intent, regardless of whether there is already an existing task running the same thing.
```

Using this flag along with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK will cause each activity instance to be created as a separate task and thus you can have different dialog pop ups.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add following flags to your `Intent` .

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
```